# Usar un mismo Html en diferentes páginas

Tags: javascript, phonegap, framework7

Estoy usando `Framework7` para hacer una aplicación móvil.

Esta aplicación tiene una barra de navegación común para todas las pantallas . Dentro de mi carpeta `Pages` quiero tener entonces un:

> barra_navegación_lateral.html

Esta barra de navegación quiero añadírsela en todas las demás páginas, al igual que hacemos, por ejemplo,  en `PHP` con:

> include

Mi pregunta es:
¿existe algo parecido en Framework7?

Comment: eso se realiza con panels no debes agregarse lo a cada una de tus paginas solo al index, y si tienes perfiles y los menús cambian deben ser paneles creados dinamicamente si no uno fijo serviría si tu menú es fijo

Comment: No he trabajado con el Framework7, pero si hago una similitud con Visual Studio, imagino que debería tener un contenedor padre "MasterPage" en el cual puedas agregar html que se repita en otras páginas, o como  un user control para evitar repetir el mismo fragmento html.